# How to split a hash in ruby by index ? Use case copying attributes between Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, split

Let's say I have a Rails model with a lot of attributes and I want to copy all or most of them without copying say just the ID and first few fields.  Instead of having to manually type all the field names to copy the attributes hash, what's a shortcut way to do this?

Comment: This question would be improved by providing a small example and showing the desired return value. Perhaps pull your example from your answer, and edit your answer to refer to the example in the question.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Provide us with an example or a much better description.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify all attributes *you don't want* using the [`except`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) method:

```
model_2.attributes.except(:id, :other_attribute, :and_another)
```

Comment: or `slice` to specify all attributes you want using

Comment: Consider changing that to `model_2.attributes.except(*model_2.attributes.keys.first(n))`.

Comment: I was aware of except method, but was avoiding to have to type names of attributes because I'm lazy and don't care about their names in this case ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select` and `with_index` methods for your goal:

```
model_2.attributes = model_1.attributes.select.with_index { |_, i| i >= 4 }
```

In this case you can specify any attributes position interval.

Comment: Readers are reminded that this is [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select), not [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

Comment: I think you meant model_2.attributes in left side of assignment but yes this works well too.

Answer (score 0):

Convert hash to array, select indexes, convert back to hash.  In this example I'd like to copy all the attributes from model_1 to model_2 starting at index 4. Obviously model_1 and model_2 need to be the same model

```
hash = model_1.attributes

model_2.attributes = hash.to_a[4..-1].to_h
```

Of course we could also do just

```
model_1.attributes = model_2.attributes.to_a[4..-1].to_h
```

Comment: You can use `-1` index instead `hash.length`: `model_2.attributes = hash.to_a[4..-1].to_h`

Comment: I believe you want `[4..hash_length-1]` or `[4...hash_length]`(three dots in the latter case). You could also write `[4,hash_length-4]`, but `[4,-1]` is certainly best.

Comment: ```[4..-1]``` is concise.  Like!